# About random variables and expected value

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables defined on
> $(\Omega, \mathcal G, P)$.
>
> If $M \in \mathbb B(\mathbb R)$, prove that
> $$ \int_{\{Y \in M\}} X\ \mathrm dP = E(X) P_Y(M), $$ where $P_Y$ is the
> probability measure induced by $Y$ on $(\mathbb R, \mathbb B(\mathbb
>  R))$.

So far I tried to work with the RHS:
$$E(X)P_Y(M) = \left(\int_{\Omega}X\ \mathrm dP\right) P_Y(M) = \int_{\Omega}P_Y(M) X\ \mathrm  dP = \int_{\Omega}P(\{ Y \in M\}) X\ \mathrm  dP $$

**Question:** But I don't know what else to do. Also, I don't see how the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent can help.

Comment: The left hand side is $E[1_{\{Y \in M\}} X]$.

Comment: But it should be assumed that $E[|X|]<\infty$. Else we can define $Y=0$ and $M=\{1\}$ and let $E[X]=\infty$, to incorrectly "conclude" that $0=0\cdot \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so are $X$ and $\mathbf{1}_{\{Y \in M\}}$.

> $$\int_{\{Y \in M\}} X \text{d}P = \int_\Omega \mathbf{1}_{\{Y\in M\}} X \text{d}P = \int_\Omega X \text{d}P\int_\Omega \mathbf{1}_{\{Y\in M\}} \text{d}P = E(X)P_Y(M).$$